# How did iOS set UIViewController's view frame before shown?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am not familiar with iOS UIViewController's detail implement. I have the following code to create a new UIViewController and show it, but the frame I set during *initWithFrame* method does not worked, the controller's view always is fullscreen(320*480).

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// view
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 130)];
viewController.view = view;
[view release];
AppController *app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UINavigationController *nav = [app navController];
[nav pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
 [viewController release];
```

I search releative thoughts in apple developer documents, but I found nothing useful for this. How did UIViewController deal with its view frame property before show it? Where can I found useful documentation.

Thank you.

---

Update: In fact, the code is from cocos2d-iphone DirectorTest: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/release-2.0-rc1/tests/DirectorTest.m#L143

Comment: are you sure you don't see the navigation controllers view bellow? Have you tried setting custom color for the background? Also your navigation is wrong. If this code is in view controller - use `self.navigationController` to reach navigation controller and push new view controller on top of it.

Comment: @Eimantas I update, this code is from cocos2d test, and it runs normal, the view is shown full screen, even it frame was set as (0, 0, 160, 240)

Comment: this code is just a badly written test case and should not be used in a real application. however, notice that the view frame can change depending on the autoresizing mask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got this all wrong - you really need to read (and understand) Apple's `UIViewController` docs:

[View Controller Catalog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313)

[View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

[View Controller Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you're creating a view in code for a view controller, you should do it in the view controller's `loadView` method.

Directly from Apple's documentation:

> **Creating a View Programmatically**
>
> If you prefer to create views programmatically ...
>    ***you do so by overriding your view controller’s loadView
>   method***. Your implementation of this method should do the following:
>
> Create a root view object. The root view contains all other views
>   associated with your view controller. You typically define the frame
>   for this view to match the size of the app window, which itself should
>   fill the screen. However, the frame is adjusted based on how your view
>   controller is displayed. See “View Controller View Resizing.”
>
> You can use a generic UIView object, a custom view you define, or any
>   other view that can scale to fill the screen.
>
> Create additional subviews and add them to the root view. For each
>   view, you should do the following:
>
> Create and initialize the view. For system views, you typically use
>   the initWithFrame: method to specify the initial size and position of
>   the view. Add the view to a parent view using the addSubview: method.
>   Assign the root view to the view property of your view controller.

Comment: Thank you. But could you explain the code: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/release-2.0-rc1/tests/DirectorTest.m#L143 
it not use loadView method, but assign a view to a controller.Why it worked?

Comment: They don't know what they're doing either?